# My table is not created in sqlite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a Database called location.db. After that, i tried to create a table LOCATIONS. When I do this, i don't get any error , but the table seems not be created at all. To verify the creation of table i´m using sqlite3 from command line, where i have seen that the code to create the table is ok but for any unknown reason is not in fact created. Thanks in advanced.

```
  package com.carlos.googlemapstest.db;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Carlos on 07/08/2015.
 */
public class LocationsHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //base de datos
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="location.db";
    //tabla
    private static final String TABLE_NAME="LOCATIONS";
    //columnas
    private static final String UID="_id";
    private static final String NOMBRE="Nombre";
    private static final String LATITUD="Latitud";
    private static final String LONGITUD="Longitud";
    private static final String INFO="Info";
    //database version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    //create database query
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"("+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            +NOMBRE+" VARCHAR(255),"
            +LATITUD+" REAL,"
            +LONGITUD+" REAL,"
            +INFO+" VARCHAR(255)"+")";
    //private static final String CREATE_TABLE1="CREATE TABLE PRUEBA (nombre TEXT);";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
    private Context context;

    public LocationsHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context=context;
        Toast.makeText(context,"Constructor called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"onCreate called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {

            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Error onCreate:"+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"onUpgraded called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Error onUpgrade:"+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you uninstalled the app on the device? Maybe you ran an older version of you LocationsHelper before and now you never hit onCreate. Have you verified onCreate() is called?

Comment: Try to uninstall your app and ther run it again. Also you can try to increase the database version number.

Comment: Can you post some output? More information is needed.

Comment: @PSglass       wouldnt it be better to delete the database instead of upgrading it?

Comment: @PSglass       putting context.deleteDatabase(String databaseName); inside the constructor would ensure that a fresh database is created everytime.

Comment: when i uninstall the app the database is deleted also. I have  rerun my app again and now it work great. Thank guys

Comment: @CantThinkOfAnything I think that the best check is reinstall the app. In case that reinstall did not help, there is a problem in code. Increase the DB version is faster way, but I know that there is a better solution. I suggested it only for check if code is OK.